# highchart column comparison chart like xrange

Tags: javascript, highcharts

For each date i have 4 value to compare and want to achieve

[image: want to achieve]

my best try - scatter
[image: my best try - scatter]
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tidjei/g7s5y3pz/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'scatter',
    zoomType: 'xy'
  },
  series: [{
    "name": "master-A",
    "color": "#29CC5F",
    "data": [
      [1615680000000, 200],
      [1615766400000, 210],
      [1615852800000, 220],
      [1615939200000, 210],
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "release-A",
    "color": "#999999",
    "data": [
      [1615680000000, 100],
      [1615766400000, 110],
      [1615852800000, 120],
      [1615939200000, 110],
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "master-B",
    "color": "#198CFF",
    "data": [
      [1615680000000, 300],
      [1615766400000, 310],
      [1615852800000, 320],
      [1615939200000, 310],
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "release-B",
    "color": "#CCC796",
    "data": [
      [1615680000000, 400],
      [1615766400000, 410],
      [1615852800000, 420],
      [1615939200000, 410],
    ]
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For change the shape of the markers, [in the documentation of the highcharts API says](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.scatter.marker.symbol) about using an image.

Quote:

> Additionally, the URL to a graphic can be given on this form:
> '`url(graphic.png)`'. Note that for the image to be applied to exported
> charts, its URL needs to be accessible by the export server.

The linked documentation contains an example available in jsfiddle - see [Predefined, graphic and custom markers](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-symbol/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use scatter series with defined custom shape. Example:

```
// Define a custom symbol path
Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.rectangle = function(x, y, w, h) {
    return ['M', x - 2 * w, y, 'L', x + 3 * w, y, x + 3 * w, y + h, x - 2 * w, y + h, 'z'];
};
if (Highcharts.VMLRenderer) {
    Highcharts.VMLRenderer.prototype.symbols.cross = Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.cross;
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bod4t0cf/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.marker.symbol